# SQL Server SQL multiplying Sum results when join multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

It is greatly appreciated if any one can help me out with this.

I am trying to get results from one table where i use sum() function and joins two more tables. My results are multiplying on sum column. Here is how my tables look like and my desired result

**Table 1**

```
[Id]   [Account_nbr]  [date]       [seq#]  
------------------------------------------
[1234]  [$60] [4321]  [10-15-2012]  [1]
[1234]  [$20] [4321]  [10-15-2012]  [2]
[1234]  [$30] [4321]  [10-15-2012]  [3]
[2345]  [$40] [9876]  [10-15-2012]  [1]
[3456]  [$50] [6543]  [10-15-2012]  [1]
```

**Table2**

```
[ID]      [cust_num]
---------------------        
[1234]     [8765]
[2345]     [8766]
[3456]     [8767]
```

**Table 3**

```
[cust_num]     [account_nbr]
-------------------------------     
[8765]        [4321]
[8767]        [9876]
```

My desired result will be join `Table 1`, `Table 2` using `ID` and join `Table 3` using `cust_num` and see `account_nbr` from `table 1` is matching with `account_number` in `Table 3` and if match found then

```
sum(Table1.Amount),Table1.Id,Table1.Account_nbr,Table1.Date
```

I was using a SQL query like this but my sum results are multiplying

```
SELECT 
    sum((Table1.Amount), Table1.Id, Table1.Account_nbr, Table1.Date
FROM 
    table1, table2, table3 
WHERE 
    table1.id = table2.id    
    AND table2.cust_num = table3.cust_num    
    AND table1.account_nbr = table3.account_nbr     
GROUP BY
    table1.id,table1.account_nbr,table1.date    
ORDER BY 
    table1.date DESC
```

But like I said earlier my results are multiplying. My desired results in tabular form as mentioned below

```
[Amount]     [Id]     [Account_nbr]    [Date]
---------------------------------------------------
[$110]       [1234]   [4321]           [10-15-2012]
[$40]        [2345]   [9876]           [10-15-2012]
```

The `id = 3456` should not be there because the corresponding `account_nbr` from `table1` not exist in `table3`.

Comment: why do you join? you have all the data you need on table1.

Comment: 1. Are all the values really delimited with `[`/`]` in your tables? If that was just your formatting, please consider removing the delimiters, they are a little confusing (not too much, though). 2. How many columns are actually there in `Table 1`? There seem to be 4 column headers but 5 data columns.

Answer (score 3):

You will get multiples of the expected SUMs if either `table1.id=table2.id` or `table2.cust_num=table3.cust_num` is not a 1:1 relationship.  This is called a cartesian product.  `table1.account_nbr=table3.account_nbr` alleviates it somewhat, but you can still get that cartesian product happening.

```
  SELECT sum(Amount) Amount, Id, Account_nbr, Date
    FROM table1
   WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
         FROM table2
         JOIN table3 on table2.cust_num = table3.cust_num
        WHERE table1.id = table2.id    
          AND table1.account_nbr = table3.account_nbr)
GROUP BY id, account_nbr, date    
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The above query achieves the same SUM from just table1, while testing that you can get a match all the way between t1-t2, t2-t3 and t3-t1.

Answer (score 3):

Well, here is what you need. I just don't understand how did you get 2345 in your final result, may be it's a typo?

[**SQL FIDDLE Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cf50/2)

```
select
    sum(T1.Amount) as Amount,
    T1.Id,
    T1.account_nbr,
    T1.date
from table1 as T1
    inner join table2 as T2 on T2.Id = T1.Id
    inner join table3 as T3 on T3.cust_num = T2.cust_num and T3.account_nbr = T1.account_nbr
group by
    T1.Id,
    T1.account_nbr,
    T1.date
```

Comment: +1 for using **proper ANSI JOIN syntax** instead of just having a comma-separated list of tables....

Comment: Thanks I really don't like that comna separated syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to calculate the sums first AND THEN do all the other  operations.

```
SELECT T1.amount AS Amount, 
       T1.id, 
       T1.account_nbr, 
       T1.DATE 
FROM   (SELECT SUM(t1.amount) AS Amount, 
               t1.id, 
               t1.account_nbr, 
               t1.DATE 
        FROM   table1 
        GROUP  BY t1.id, 
                  t1.account_nbr, 
                  t1.DATE)AS T1 
       inner join table2 AS T2 
               ON T2.id = T1.id 
       inner join table3 AS T3 
               ON T3.cust_num = T2.cust_num 
                  AND T3.account_nbr = T1.account_nbr'
```